# Video is not paused when hold mode ON

Tags: video, mode, pausing-execution

I submitted my app to samsung market but they refused it saying that video is not pausing when hold mode ON.

Does anyone help me to understand what code I have to add? that's my clipvidoe activity

```
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Clipvideo1 extends Activity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
setContentView(R.layout.clip1);

VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

Uri videoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.fiordi6);

videoView.setVideoURI(videoPath);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
Toast.makeText(this, "Regia di Angelo Giammarresi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible nobody knows where do I have to put hands to check this strange situation of video sounds that doesn't stop when the alarm start ringing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the pause/resume states of the activity cycle by implementing the onPause and onResume methods. Of course you stop the video in the onPause method (and maybe save the video tracking information) and you restart it in the onResume method (making the video continue from where it was stopped using the stored tracking information).

Comment: Thank you, I try to understand your suggestion and implement it then I let you know the result.